# Space on left and right in a 100% width flex container with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that is `100%` width with a horizontal scroll. I want to have space on left and right in the scroll, but `margin-right` of the divs doesn't create space on the right side, also I have another container wrapping the container to hide the scrollBar with padding-bottom.

I know that I can use `white-space: nowrap` in a block container in which `margin-right` works, but I want to use `flex-box`. Also I am setting the divs' `width` with `min-width`:

Also I know that in this case `min-width: 22% = 22vw`, but I want to do it with percantage.
[jsfiddle code open](https://jsfiddle.net/93wvu1g8/)

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div{
    height: 100%;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div{
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.container > div > div{
  min-width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand: would you like to have space on the right and on the left inside the container?

Comment: @kadash When you open the jsfiddle you can see that there is white space before the first red div, but when you scroll the horizontal scroll there is no white space after the last red div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is little trick about the `margin-right` which wasn't applied on the last div you can
easily add another `div` and make it small as possible for example like `0.1px` but if it is `0px` it won't work this will make the last div left space between them but the last `div` will not be visible so it will sound like its `margin` has been applied

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div>div {
  min-width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  background: red;
}

.container>div>div:last-child {
  min-width: 0.1px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the issue is your `min-width` setting. 20% of 100 would only allow 5 blocks without spacing. 7 blocks would need to be ~14% + spacing to allow enough room. So you can take out the `min-width`, convert your `margin` spacing to something proportional and add `flex:1` to `.container > div > div`. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mister_pea/7394mydk/12/)

Comment: I don't think you have understood my question I want to have a scroll and I want my divs to be 20% of the view. The scroll is intended I don't want to fit the divs in the body's width the only thing I want is the scroll to have padding on left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Gad answer:
There is option to not add additional div at the end. You can just use pseudo element ::after/::before and then add something like this. Important note is fact that then div with after pseudo element needs to be position: relative.

```
.container>div>div:last-child::after {
  content: " ";
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0b4tm5y3/4/